# Array of bitwise values with names, how to check against a value

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, bit-manipulation

I have a database table with a list of names, with bitwise values associated, i can create a php array without any real issue, but i need to be able to check with another query which of the resulting conditions it maps to in the array, then display the name associated.

[image: Conditions Bitwise table]

```
$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$SystemDB", $myUser, $myPass);
$DBH1 = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$TaxiHistoryDB", $myUser, $myPass);


$sth = $DBH->prepare("SELECT dbo.Conditions.Name, dbo.Conditions.ConditionValue     
                      FROM dbo.Conditions 
                      WHERE dbo.Conditions.ConditionID > 0");
$sth->execute();

$ConditionsArray = $sth->fetchAll();

$STH1 = $DBH1->query("SELECT dbo.tblBooking.Conditions 
                      FROM dbo.tblBooking  
                      WHERE dbo.tblBooking.BookingID = '36607762'");

$STH1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

while($row1 = $STH1->fetch()){

$condition = $row1->Conditions;


}//end while
```

the first query gives me a result that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 2 [1] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 4 [1] => 4 ) 
[3] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 8 [1] => 8 ) 
[4] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 16 [1] => 16 ) 
[5] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 32 [1] => 32 ) 
[6] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 64 [1] => 64 ) 
[7] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 128 [1] => 128 ) 
[8] => Array ( [Name] => Exterior Hoist [0] => Exterior Hoist [ConditionValue] => 256 [1] => 256 ) 
[9] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 512 [1] => 512 ) 
[10] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1024 [1] => 1024 ) 
[11] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 2048 [1] => 2048 ) 
[12] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 4096 [1] => 4096 ) 
[13] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 8192 [1] => 8192 ) 
[14] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 16384 [1] => 16384 ) 
[15] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 32768 [1] => 32768 ) 
[16] => Array ( [Name] => Parcel [0] => Parcel [ConditionValue] => 65536 [1] => 65536 ) 
[17] => Array ( [Name] => Cheques [0] => Cheques [ConditionValue] => 131072 [1] => 131072 )
[18] => Array ( [Name] => OuterArea [0] => OuterArea [ConditionValue] => 262144 [1] => 262144 ) 
[19] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 524288 [1] => 524288 ) 
[20] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1048576 [1] => 1048576 ) 
[21] => Array ( [Name] => V [0] => V [ConditionValue] => 2097152 [1] => 2097152 )
[22] => Array ( [Name] => Wheelchair [0] => Wheelchair [ConditionValue] => 4194304 [1] => 4194304 ) 
[23] => Array ( [Name] => M50 [0] => M50 [ConditionValue] => 8388608 [1] => 8388608 ) 
[24] => Array ( [Name] => Executive Car (Silver) [0] => Executive Car (Silver) [ConditionValue] => 16777216 [1] => 16777216 ) 
[25] => Array ( [Name] => Two M50s [0] => Two M50s [ConditionValue] => 33554432 [1] => 33554432 ) 
[26] => Array ( [Name] => Special [0] => Special [ConditionValue] => 67108864 [1] => 67108864 ) 
[27] => Array ( [Name] => Animal [0] => Animal [ConditionValue] => 134217728 [1] => 134217728 ) 
[28] => Array ( [Name] => COD Parcel [0] => COD Parcel [ConditionValue] => 268435456 [1] => 268435456 ) 
[29] => Array ( [Name] => 9 seater [0] => 9 seater [ConditionValue] => 536870912 [1] => 536870912 ) 
[30] => Array ( [Name] => 6 seater [0] => 6 seater [ConditionValue] => 1073741824 [1] => 1073741824 ) 
[31] => Array ( [Name] => 7 seater [0] => 7 seater [ConditionValue] => 2147483648 [1] => 2147483648 ) 
[32] => Array ( [Name] => Wagon [0] => Wagon [ConditionValue] => 4294967296 [1] => 4294967296 ) 
[33] => Array ( [Name] => Maxi10str [0] => Maxi10str [ConditionValue] => 8589934592 [1] => 8589934592 ) 
[34] => Array ( [Name] => Bike [0] => Bike [ConditionValue] => 17179869184 [1] => 17179869184 ) 
[35] => Array ( [Name] => NonMaxi [0] => NonMaxi [ConditionValue] => 34359738368 [1] => 34359738368 ) 
[36] => Array ( [Name] => NonMaxiOrMulti [0] => NonMaxiOrMulti [ConditionValue] => 68719476736 [1] => 68719476736 ) 
[37] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 137438953472 [1] => 137438953472 ) 
[38] => Array ( [Name] => Towbar [0] => Towbar [ConditionValue] => 274877906944 [1] => 274877906944 ) 
[39] => Array ( [Name] => NO DISPATCH [0] => NO DISPATCH [ConditionValue] => 549755813888 [1] => 549755813888 ) )
```

I've read a few posts on here and a couple elsewhere, i understand how bitwise operations work, but i'm a little lost with the syntax or process that i would go by. essentially, a job number will have between 0 and 40 conditions associated with it.

with the following code in the while loop

> echo $row1->Conditions;

I get: **67108864**

which i know represents "special"

im just not sure how to compare the results from the second query to the array that the first query makes.

thanks.

Comment: Why have you 2 databases??

Comment: @davidstrachan thats how the system was setup before i arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like:

```
while($bookingRow = $STH1->fetch())
{    
    foreach($ConditionsArray as $codeRow)
    {
        if(($bookingRow->Conditions & $codeRow->ConditionValue) > 0)
        {
            printf('Matched Condition Name: %s', $bookingRow->Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But you probably want to select at least one additional column in your second query, so that you know what row from the `tblBooking`  table matched.

Also, if your condition codes are really just equal to 2^*n*, it would have been *much* more efficient to store *n*, rather than waste all those bits storing zeros.

The number 4294967296 requires 33 bits.  If you instead stored *n* (=32), you would require only 6.

And I'm guessing that if a booking has multiple conditions then it's value is just the sum of the various condition codes, since adding multiple (2^*n*)'s together (for different *n*'s) gives you an integer value that you can reverse back into condition codes.

But this defeats the purpose of databases.  If you *really* wanted that, you should have had 3 tables: a conditionCode table (indexed by a simple incrementing integer primary key), a booking table (indexed similarly), and then a third table maybe "bookingCondition" where there is a row for each condition that each booking has.

If booking 1 has 2 conditions, booking 2 has 5 and booking 3 has 1, your "bookingCondition" table would have 8 rows, looking something like

```
1 a
1 b
2 c
2 d
2 e
2 f
2 g
3 h
```

Where the letters a-h aren't actually letters, but instead integers, references to the primary key of the conditionCode table.

Then figuring out what conditions a specific booking had would be as easy as one simple SQL statement (using JOINs), instead of multiple queries and PHP "post-processing"

Comment: I had already done something similar to this, but i get strange results, most of the conditions are found true, when they shouldnt be. for example, the example used in the question, the only values evaluated to be false are 1, 8, 1024. when the only one that should be found true is 67108864, therefore every other value should in theory be found to be false.

Comment: Check your code, [this snippet](http://ideone.com/nitIgT) illustrates how you might check that value (67108864).

Comment: any chance u can explain to me whats going on there?

Comment: just a note, not that i think it matters, this is running on a 32bit operating system.